Having trouble with negative lookahead regex in python
So, I have to match everything before the last open-close parenthesis and get that in group. And after the last open-close parenthesis try to get the value with some pattern, again in group.
This is my sample example:
ID  pqr () name:123.

And this is my regex:
^(?P<JUNK>.*?)(?!\(.\))(\(.*\))?\sname\:(?P<name>\d+)\.$

And now with this I am getting ID  pqr  for JUNK key and 123 for name key which is perfect.
And now, with this regex, it's working fine for below strings:

ID pqr (a) () name:123.
ID  pqr (a) (b) () name:123.
ID  pqr (a) (b) () name:123.
ID  pqr (a) (b) (XX) name:123.

in returns I am getting these outputs:

{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID pqr (a) ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID pqr (a) (b) ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID pqr (a) (b) ', 'name': '123'}

So far, it's working fine with above strings, but for the below ones I am having some trouble

ID  pqr (a) (b) (X) name:123.
ID  pqr (aa) (b) (X) name:123.
ID  pqr (a) (bb) (X) name:123.

For these strings, I am getting output like this:

{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr (a) (b) (X)', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr (a) ', 'name': '123'}

But basically I want like this:

{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr (a) (b) ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr (aa) (b) ', 'name': '123'}
{'JUNK': 'ID  pqr (a) (bb) ', 'name': '123'}

This is my regex101 attempt: https://regex101.com/r/AV8WlB/4
Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Just to clarify: you do not want ^(?P<JUNK>.*)(\(.*\))\s+name\:(?P<name>\d+)\.$ because the parentheses can be missing?

Do you want ^(?P<JUNK>.*?)(\([^)]*\))(?!.*\([^)]*\))\sname\:(?P<name>\d+)\.$? https://regex101.com/r/0SqVPG/1

Both are working good, but I am looking for lazy match rather than greedy.

For which input do the above regexes not work as expected (as too greedy) ?

A lazy version could be like this ^(?P<JUNK>.*?)(\([^()]*\))\s+name:(?P<name>\d+)\.$ https://regex101.com/r/pzCzlF/1 But the non lazy version would also match.

Try:
^(?P<JUNK>.*?)(\([^)]*\)\s)?name:(?P<name>\d+)\.$

See: regex101

Explanation

^: Start of string...
(?P<JUNK>.*?): followed by JUNK...
(\([^)]*\)\s)?: then, if applicable the last pair of brackets...
name:: before literal "name:"...
(?P<name>\d+): and collecting the number before...
\.$: final "." at the end of the string.

